# View List - Android Studio = Navigation Drawer Layout

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am a beginner in Android Studio and I need to help. I'm trying to make App on Navigation Drawer Layout. So, I found a tutorial how to get a specific layout when I click on something in Navigation Drawer Menu

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg&list=PLQIC834Sj9LcamgQ8JhpsRqPD9NFNjG0Q

Works Perfect!

Just now I want to make ViewList in one layout of them I'm refering from Main Navigation Menu so I found next tutorial (http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/start-new-activity-from-android-listview-onitem-clicked.html).

I tried to apply ListView Tutorial on a brand-new project and it works perfectly! Problem is when I want to apply this to my project where I have already used Navigation on specific layouts with fragments. It says there is some duplication.

Here is my MainActivity:

```css
package com.example.martin.ultimateenglish;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.list) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new First_Layout())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_changelog) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new Changelog())
                    .commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Could you help me? It seems I can't use name of a class more than once but make this two tutorials together is unbelieveable hard for me now! I just want to have Navigation Drawer Layout with Menu Items refering to specific layouts where I want to apply Viewlist.

Thank you for every advice or answer.

Martin U.